# Add an menu order for custom post types - WITHOUT A PLUGIN

Tags: wordpress, function, action, custom-post-type

I would like to add an action of some sort to place an order menu to custom post types. Giving my clients the opportunity to change the order of their posts.

I would like to do this without a plugin though. Better for optimization.

Thanks in advance.